# send mail show bootstrap alert ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to do so that when we send an email through the contact form it sends the email and there is a bootstrap alert that comes out email sent. there you can see all my code html : https://jsfiddle.net/6rfeas35/ and this is my php code in

AJAX JQuery in bottom of index.php

```
   <script>
       AOS.init();
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               const $this = $(this);

               // disable submit button
               const $button = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]').text('Submit...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

               // send message
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'contact.php',
                   data: $this.serialize(),
                   success: function(data){
                       alert("E-mail envoyé avec succès ! Merci pour votre message ! Une réponse vous sera apportée dans les plus brefs délais.");
                        $this[0].reset(); // reset form
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                       alert('An error occurred. Please try again')
                   },
                   complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                       // enable submit button
                       $button.text('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                   }
               })
           })
       })
   </script>
```

contact.php

```
 <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST["send"])){

    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '73.auto.73@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'rlylecrtuvztqosz';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port = 465;      
    $mail->setFrom('73.auto.73@gmail.com');

    $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Projet web';
    $mail->Body = "Message:" . $body . "<br>Phone number: " . $phone . "<br>Name: " . $name . "<br>Mail: " . $email;

    $mail->send();

    echo "success";
    
}
```

The bootstrap alert goes out but the email is not sent, I don't understand why. if I remove the ajax jquery code the email is sent but it opens a blank page where it says success, how can I do so that there is the sending of email and the bootstrap alert?

Comment: in your PHP part, return ``success`` or ``true`` and in your front end part, use ajax and call the endpoint that sends the email, and success call back function of ajax, check if the endpoint returns true or "success" then show the alert/

Comment: Is the email successfully sent via ajax?

Comment: @OMi Shah I have use ajax you can check in jsfiddle link but don't know why do this

Comment: @ruleboy21 if i delete ajax mail send, if i don't delete jquery ajax only boootstrap alert work mail don't sended

Comment: Print your ajax formData to see if it's what you expect and wrap your PHP code with `try/catch` so you will be able to catch an error.

Comment: @n1md7 i have edit my question and put ajax jquery

Comment: All I'm saying is to print the input payload(`var_dump($_POST);`) in your PHP code and compare what is different from the case that works for you

Comment: @n1md7 in which line i nee to put this?

Comment: In your php file before if statement should work. Alternatively you can check your browser network tab what data is sent to your php endpoint. You can make sure if something is missing or the format is incorrect.

Comment: @n1md7 problem not in php because it's send mail but when i add jquery ajax it's only show alert not send mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're checking if `isset($_POST["send"])` in the contact.php file, you have to ensure that an input with `name="send"` exist in the form in the index.php file.

- Add `name="send"` to a hidden field in the form and remove it from
  the submit button.

index.php

https://jsfiddle.net/r1jwn8kb/

contact.php

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST["send"])){

    $body = $_POST['message'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '73.auto.73@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'rlylecrtuvztqosz';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port = 465;      
    $mail->setFrom('73.auto.73@gmail.com');

    $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]);

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Projet web';
    $mail->Body = "Message:" . $body . "<br>Phone number: " . $phone . "<br>Name: " . $name . "<br>Mail: " . $email;

    $mail->send();

    echo "success";
    die;
}
```

Comment: Problem not in php but in jquery and ajax i think because if i delete jquery ajax mail send, and when i  add jquery ajax only have alert

Comment: I've fixed that, did you check out the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r1jwn8kb/?

Comment: I have see but this not resolved issus, because it's show alert but don't send mail

Comment: What alert does it show?

Comment: see this : E-mail envoyé avec succès ! Merci pour votre message ! Une réponse vous sera apportée dans les plus brefs délais. but mail don't send

Comment: Now, remove the jquery in the index.php file and also remove `die;` from the contact.php and see if you get the email.

Comment: yes mail send with and whithout die; and exit;